# Asynchronously bind column in GridView (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview

Is there a way to bind one specific column in a GridView control asynchronously?

In my situation I am asked to make a list of customers AND show for each customer their current Azure usage (I will use the Partner Center SDK to retrieve this information). The result will should look something like this (of course there will be multiple record):

```
Customer name | Billing start date | Billing end date | Usage
ACME Inc      | 10/20/2016         | 11/21/2016       | $100,00
Microsoft     | 10/20/2016         | 11/21/2016       | <loading...>
```

This means I need to do the following API calls:

1. Call the API to get a list of all customers
2. For each customer make a call to get the usage data

I would like to be able to present the user with a GridView displaying all the customers and show the usage data when they come available. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what gridview are we talking about here?

Comment: If possible the standard ASP.NET GridView control. But I am open for other possibilities.

Comment: I would say don't use asp GridView if you are using MVC. That was for classic asp

Comment: You are right let's make it the Grid control (always mix them up)

Comment: you mean bootstrap Grid system??? because MVC does not comes with any web control at all...native html controls are all you have

Comment: After more careful consideration I don't mean the Bootstrap Grid System. I really mean something like a sortable table. I have seen Bootstraps solutions (like "https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html"), but I am not sure how good they will work. I do have access to the Syncfusion Data Grid control.